# wxStyledTextCtrl: Autocomplete Image displays incorrectly

Tags: c++, autocomplete, wxwidgets, wxstyledtextctrl

I need help with Autocomplete box with Images. I cannot get it display
correctly. I have tried with wxArtProvider bitmaps as well as custom
ones but result is the same. Bitmaps are 16x16. screen shot can be
seen below. Images are a bit hidden not fully visible (see the red ring)

[image]

Here is a relevant/sample code:

```
    RegisterImage(1, wxBitmap(ConfigManager::Instance()->GetIconPath()+wxT("keyword.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG));
```

And catching characters as they are typed I use

```
//Auto complete function
void CMainFrame::OnAutoComplete(wxKeyEvent& e) {
        if(e.GetKeyCode()==32 && e.ControlDown()) {
                m_editor->AutoCompSetIgnoreCase(false) ;
                m_editor->AutoCompShow(3, wxT("private?1  protected?1  public?1
static?2 switch?2 throw?2  try?2  use?3 var?3 while?3 xor?3"));
        }
        else {
                e.Skip();
        } 
}
```

Note that my system of getting auto complete is complex and I decided to replace with this easy one but it reproduces the problem. I use wxWidgets 2.9 trunk version on Ubuntu Oneiric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug and it is fixed as of latest SVN version. There is upgrade also to almost latest version of scintilla. So all is well now!